# DJI SDK - Sample tutorials in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I was going through the DJI SDK and looking through the sample tutorials like TapFly and ActiveTrack Missions etc. but could only find the code in Objective C. Although they have mentioned that the code is available in Swift but I couldn't find it. Also, if it's only available in obj c, can I use the bridging header for the code using without making many changes in obj c while running my app coded in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the MSDK-iOS is compatible with your Swift app

Comment: I found the sample code for the DJI SDK for iOS in swift but not for the TapFLy and ActiveTrack Missions. I want to work on it to explore the possible ways to customize it. Please let me know if there is any other sample for tutorials in swift.